# How to use sortBy using react datepicker and lodash

Tags: lodash, react-datepicker

I want to sort my events based on the dates the user gives them. I am using react datepicker and Lodash to sort the events desc.

My code React JS

```
const events = _.sortBy(this.props.events, [["seconds"]])
    console.log(JSON.stringify(events))
```

Output console.log

```
[
{"date":{"seconds":416617200,"nanoseconds":0},,"title":"Past event 1983"},
{"date":{"seconds":1995231600,"nanoseconds":0},"title":"Future event 2033"},
{"date":{"seconds":1585090800,"nanoseconds":0},"title":"Present event 2020"},
{date":{"seconds":1677625200,"nanoseconds":0},"title":"Future event 2023"}
]
```

When I am trying orderBy "date" I also don't get the desired result

```
const events = _orderBy(this.props.events, "date")
console.log(JSON.stringify(events))
```

console.log:

```
[
{"date":{"seconds":1995231600,"nanoseconds":0},"title":"Future event 2033"},
{"date":{"seconds":1585090800,"nanoseconds":0},"title":"Present event 2020"},
{date":{"seconds":1677625200,"nanoseconds":0},"title":"Future event 2023"}
{"date":{"seconds":416617200,"nanoseconds":0},,"title":"Past event 1983"},
]
```

As you can see the seconds are not orderBy correctly in both cases.

Please advise how to use orderBy with Lodash when using React Date Picker?

Many thanks

Comment: Try `_orderBy(this.props.events, ["date.seconds"], ["desc"])`

Comment: If you check this JSFiddle you will see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/guilhermetoti/h58p3ytm/2/

Comment: You are a legend! This made my day! Thanks Guilherme!

Comment: You're welcome, my friend!

Comment: @GuilhermeToti since you helped me out last time. Could you help me with this new questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61319995/how-to-setup-dynamic-routing-with-react-router-based-on-props-received