# How to setup dynamic routing with React Router based on props received?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a blogging App in react JS and would like to change the URL path when navigating to a blog article. However, I am running into a problem when using '/:id' in Route with React Router Dom.

Example when navigating to these two URLs:

```
Blog article URL:
https://website.com/myfirstblogpost/4582819

Profile page URL:
https://website.com/profile/902310
```

App.js setup

```
<Route path="/:id/:id" component={BlogArticle} exact={true} />
<Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} exact={true}/>
```

With this setup, my blog article is being shown on both the blog article route AND profile route. How do I fix this problem? Is it possible to do render a route like:

```
<Route path=`{/${blog.title}/${blog.id}}` component={BlogArticle} exact={true} />
<Route path=`{/profile/${user.id}`component={Profile} exact={true}/>
```

If so how if not what other solutions are there? Please note that due to SEO reasons the blog article title must be shown directly after the first '/' e.g. website.com/blogarticle

Many thanks guys!

Kind regards,

Frido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes you need to do:

**First:** As the "profile" is hard-coded, you need to swap the order and put it in first position:

```
<Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} exact={true}/>
<Route path="/:id/:id" component={BlogArticle} exact={true} />
```

This way, React Router will first search for those "hard-coded" URLs, and then check the variable ones.

**Second:** You can't have two equal arguments on your URL if they are different (First is a string, probably a slug. Second is an integer). So you will need to modify it as:

```
<Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} exact={true}/>
<Route path="/:title/:id" component={BlogArticle} exact={true} />
```

This may do the trick!

Comment: You're a legend! It is working! Many thanks again Guilherme!

Comment: Hi Guilherme, since you are my legend. Could you look into this problem I encounter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405696/how-to-setup-react-redux-firestore-in-next-js many thanks!!!

Comment: Oh @FridovanDriem, sorry man, never used neither NEXT.JS and firebase :(